# How can I describe these windows?

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say I have two windows in my room, both at opposite ends. While one window is connected to another room, the other one is an **outer window**; by that I mean that, if you open it, you will see the view of outside. The first window **goes inside another room**.

How can I differentiate between the above mentioned windows? Do the highlighted phrases correctly describe what I want to say?

Comment: First type is 'window facing the outside of the house'. See Matt's answer for the second window type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would call windows that look *out* of the house **exterior windows** and refer to windows pointing to other rooms of the house **interior windows**.